# Webdriver in Python: How to get number of rows.columns and data?

Tags: python-2.7, webdriver

Any idea how to get number of rows and columns and data from  table? I am using webdriver Python bindings.

I tried different approaches but did not success.

```
table = self.find_element_by_xpath(id)
trs = self._selobj.find_element_by_tag_name("tr")
print "Getteble 2 "
print "TRS " + trs[1]
tds = trs[1].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
print tds[0]
#print table.__len__()
#for(int i=1;i<=list.length;i++)
print "Tesxt 1"
text1 = self._selobj.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='general_table']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2‌​]/a").text
print "Tesxt " + text1
#text2 = self._selobj.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='general_table']/div["+i+"]/div[2‌​]").text;
```

Comment: can we see what you've tried?

Comment: table = self.find_element_by_xpath(id)



trs = self._selobj.find_element_by_tag_name("tr")
print "TRS " + trs[1]
tds = trs[1].find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")
print tds[0]

Comment: did not get you. "Correct the body if needed"???

Comment: I put your code in the body of the question where it belongs. Because formatting was not preserved in the comment, I had to use my best judgement as to what your code is supposed to look like. Now you could edit your question to make sure that code looks like intended.

Comment: I also tried                                                           table = self._selobj.find_element_by_xpath(id)   
        print table
        for td in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
            print "Text is " + td

Comment: table = self._selobj.find_element_by_xpath(id)   
print table
for td in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('td'):
print "Text is " + td

Answer (score 1):

try this ..

```
table=driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath of table")
for tr in table.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr"):
print(tr.text)
```